# Seleccionar el inicio a final de un array PHP

Tags: php, array

Buenas quiero saber si hay una posibilidad que en PHP pueda obtener todos los datos de un array para meterlo en un else if

```
    $afr_shipping = array(
        0 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7463', //Recibelo Hoy
        1 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7462', //Recibelo Mañana
        2 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7729', //Recibelo Lunes (VIE)
        3 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7527', //Recibelo Lunes (SAB)
        4 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7528', //Recibelo Martes (SAB)
        5 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7731', //Recibelo Martes (DOM)
        6 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7730', //Recibelo Martes (LUN)
        7 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7529', //Recibelo Miercoles (LUN)
        8 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7732', //Recibelo Miercoles (MAR)
        9 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7530', //Recibelo Jueves (MAR)
        10 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7733', //Recibelo Jueves (MIE)
        11 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7531', //Recibelo Viernes (MIE)
        12 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7734', //Recibelo Viernes (JUE)
        13 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7532', //Recibelo Sabado (JUE)
        14 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7735' //Recibelo Sabado (VIE)
    );
```

Datos del array que quiero obtener para usarlo en el siguiente código:

```
 else if ( $chosen_shipping == 'SD' || $chosen_shipping == 'ND' || $chosen_shipping == $afr_shipping[0] || $chosen_shipping == $afr_shipping[0] //Aqui van todos los arrays) {
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
```

Quiero chequear que desde los datos desde el [0 -> 14] se seteen en el else if del $afr_shipping[0]

Desde ya gracias.

PD: ya he probado usando el siguiente código que me han sugerido pero tira error:

```
else if ( $chosen_shipping == 'SD' || $chosen_shipping == 'ND'){    
   foreach ($afr_shipping as $value) {
      unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
      unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
  }
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda de todos pude conseguir hacer funcionar, dejo el código.

```
function o9113_payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
    $afr_shipping = array(
        //Lista 99MIN para los tipos de envios para Pagos con Tarjeta No borrar a menos que sea necesario.
        0 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7463', //Recibelo Hoy
        1 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7462', //Recibelo Mañana
        2 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7729', //Recibelo Lunes (VIE)
        3 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7527', //Recibelo Lunes (SAB)
        4 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7528', //Recibelo Martes (SAB)
        5 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7731', //Recibelo Martes (DOM)
        6 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7730', //Recibelo Martes (LUN)
        7 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7529', //Recibelo Miercoles (LUN)
        8 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7732', //Recibelo Miercoles (MAR)
        9 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7530', //Recibelo Jueves (MAR)
        10 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7733', //Recibelo Jueves (MIE)
        11 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7531', //Recibelo Viernes (MIE)
        12 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7734', //Recibelo Viernes (JUE)
        13 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7532', //Recibelo Sabado (JUE)
        14 => 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7735' //Recibelo Sabado (VIE)
    );
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
    //Entonces si customer->get_billing_state no es igual a LMA o CAL (Lima o Callao) 
    //Quita el pago en efectivo y deja solo el pago con tarjeta
    if ( WC()->customer->get_billing_state() != 'LMA' && WC()->customer->get_billing_state() != 'CAL' ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    //Entonces si $chosen_shipping es = a SD -> ND -> afr_shipping = pago con tarjeta
    } else if( in_array($chosen_shipping, array('SD','ND')) || in_array($chosen_shipping, array_keys($afr_shipping)) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Comment: Agrega un `foreach` dentro de el `else if` y remueve la condición de la sentencia original

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero no sabria como implementarlo ya que no lo he podido implementar con el foreach.

Comment: No agregues código en los comentarios, en cambio, haz clic en [edit] y agrega esa información en la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa, ya lo he arreglado, como dije arriba. No puedo insertar el foreach dentro del else if porque me tira error.

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que necesitas: ¿Quieres chequear en el `else if` que $chosen_shipping tenga alguno de los valores del array $afr_shipping?. No entiendo esta frase: "Quiero chequear que desde los datos desde el [0 -> 14] se seteen en el else if del $afr_shipping[0]".

Comment: Prueba con `else if( in_array($chosen_shipping, array('SD','ND')) || in_array($chosen_shipping, array_keys($afr_shipping)) ){`

Comment: @Sal muchas gracias tu código me ha funcionado perfectamente!

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal podrías intentar primero declarar una variable que te permita verificar si un elemento de afr_shipping ha sido seleccionado.

```
$afr_shipping_check = false;
```

Para el siguiente ejemplo simulando la elección del usuario he declarado esta variable $afr_choosen con uno de los valores del arreglo.

```
$afr_choosen = 'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:7528';
```

Luego de eso recorres el arreglo con un forEach y si el elemento ingresado por el usuario existe ($afr_choosen) cambias el valor de $afr_shipping_check por true.

```
foreach($afr_shipping as $shipping) {
  if($shipping == $afr_choosen) {
    $afr_shipping_check = true;
  }
}
```

Finalmente hacemos uso de esta variable $afr_shipping_check en nuestro ciclo.

```
if(someCondition) {
   
} else if ( $chosen_shipping == 'SD' || $chosen_shipping == 'ND' || 
    $afr_shipping_check) {
        var_dump('Se ha seleccionado un elemento de afr_shipping');
}
```

No se si esto se ajusta a lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero en si estabas casi en lo correcto pero yo quería traer todo lo del array, no elegir de a 1, pero igual se adapta muchas gracias!